# Attribute auto_now_add not working properly on google endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I am using google app engine endpoints to create an API, so I designed my models using the predefined attributes for updatedDate `auto_now`, and for createdDate `auto_now_add`. The updatedDate column is filled correctly but not the createdDate is always None.

Here's the code I am using to persist my entities:

```
  @endpoints.method(PartyForm, PartyForm, path='parties', http_method='POST', name='insert')
  def insert(self, request):
    data = {field.name: getattr(request, field.name) for field in request.all_fields()}

    if data['launchDate']:
      data['launchDate'] = datetime.strptime(data['launchDate'][:10], "%Y-%m-%d").date()

    p_id = Party.allocate_ids(size=1)[0]
    p_key = ndb.Key(Party, p_id)
    data['key'] = p_key

    Party(**data).put()
    return request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours, I found why the attribute `auto_now_add` didn't work. In my model file, I created two classes:

- `Party(ndb.Model)`: This is the ndb model
- `PartyForm(messages.Message)`: This is the endpoint form class model

The error was that in my endpoint form class model `PartyForm`, I added the attributes createdDate, and updatedDate. For some reason the updatedDate worked but not the createdDate. And after I removed this attributes from my form class model, all was working correctly.